# Javascript onMouseover to swap images

Tags: javascript, html, image, onmouseover

I have some code that makes an image larger when moused over:

```
<script>
function bigImg(x)
{
x.style.height="70px";
x.style.width="237px";
}

function normalImg(x)
{
x.style.height="56px";
x.style.width="218px";
}
</script>
```

and I call those functions with:

```
<a><img border="0" src="category_icons/addorder.png" onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)"></a>
```

But what I would really like to do is make it so the `bigIMG(x)` function also changes the image. I'm not extremely familiar with javascript and was wondering if someone knew what I can code in, to swap the image. The image name is addorder2.png. I've tried using `this.src="addorder2.png"; but that is not working.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do. Change the image src into "addorder2.png".

```
<script>
function bigImg(x)
{
    x.style.height="70px";
    x.style.width="237px";
    x.src = "addorder2.png";
}

function normalImg(x)
{
    x.style.height="56px";
    x.style.width="218px";
    x.src = " addorder.png";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Oh dang it. I'm not that good with javascript and I was using "this.src..." instead of "x.src"

Comment: Nope. Once you enter the bigImg function this is scoped to the window. Glad I could help :).

Answer (score 3):

My 2 cents:

[**LIVE DEMONSTRATION**](http://jsbin.com/kifivuji/2/edit)

Don't use inline JS, rather you can set a `data.*` attribute
and an object literal that will contain your desired changes
and read it with JS:

```
<img class="zoom" src="img.jpg" data-enlarge='{"src":"img2.jpg", "zoom":"1.2"}'>
```

As you can see above we'll target with JS every element with class *"zoom"*

```
function enlarge(){

  var el = this,
      src = el.src,
      data = JSON.parse(el.dataset.enlarge);

  el.src = data.src;
  el.style.transition = "0.3s";
  el.style.transform  = "scale("+data.zoom+")";

  el.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    el.src = src;
    el.style.transform = "scale(1)";
  },false);

}

var $ZOOM = document.querySelectorAll('.zoom');
for(var i=0; i<$ZOOM.length; i++){
  $ZOOM[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', enlarge, false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With Javascript you can edit the src attribute of the img.

Javascript:

```
function bigImg()
{
document.getElementById("myImg").src="addorder2.gif";
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id="myImg" onmouseover="bigImg()" src="addorder.png">

</body>
</html>
```

I recommend checking out [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) to learn more about [image document manipulation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp) and of course specifically getting and setting the [image src element](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_src.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Just change `x.src` property according to function:

```
function bigImg(x)
{
    x.style.height="70px";
    x.style.width="237px";
    x.src = "category_icons/addorder2.png";
}

function normalImg(x)
{
    x.style.height="56px";
    x.style.width="218px";
    x.src = "category_icons/addorder.png";
}
```