# html image change on hover

Tags: html, image, hover

I would like to ask whether it's possible to have a code for image change on hover without CSS and without the function onmouseover

For my web, I need a simple html code, unfortunately, the eshop system does not support the onmouseover function

Is it possible?

Thank you very much

Comment: Without css and js, its not possible.

Comment: Are you saying you want to do this with Javascript and not CSS? [Yes, it is possible with Javascript.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861854/javascript-onmouseover-to-swap-images)